# Laravel Multiple Joins with Count

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I try to join multiple tables with a count if i split it i can make it work but isnt there a way to do this in one statment or do i have to to do it in a other way ?

```php
 $posts = DB::table('posts')
                ->limit(5)
                ->join('badges', 'posts.badge', '=', 'badges.id')
                ->join('blog_cat', 'posts.maincat', '=', 'blog_cat.id')
                ->select('posts.*', 'badges.css' , 'badges.desc')
                ->get();

         $posts = DB::table('posts')
                    ->join('comments_blogs', 'posts.id', '=', 'comments_blogs.blog_id')
                    ->select('posts.id as id', DB::raw("count(*) as count"))
                    ->groupBy('posts.id')
                    ->get();
```

Thanks for the Help
Limuz

Comment: If it was me, I'd start with the raw MySQL

Answer (score 0):

The following can work because you are grouping by the primary key of the `posts` table. The aggregation count needs to be on the DISTINCT primary key to avoid being counted multiple times because of the other joins to `badges` and `blog_cat`.

```
$posts = DB::table('posts')
                ->limit(5)
                ->join('badges', 'posts.badge', '=', 'badges.id')
                ->join('blog_cat', 'posts.maincat', '=', 'blog_cat.id')
                ->join('comments_blogs', 'posts.id', '=', 'comments_blogs.blog_id', 'left outer')
                ->select('posts.*', 'badges.css' , 'badges.desc',DB::raw("count(distinct comments_blogs.id) as count"))
                ->groupBy('posts.id')
                ->get();
```

On its own the second one could be simplified to:

```
    $posts = DB::table('comments_blogs')
                ->select('blog_id as id', DB::raw("count(*) as count"))
                ->groupBy('blog_id')
                ->get();
```

Comment: Ah thank you i am not good at it how do i tell him to add that count to the "posts" array

Comment: Now i am at the same Error code
_SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'blogpirat.posts.user_id' isn't in GROUP BY_

I couldnt figure it out it sounds me he whants every "select" in the group by

Comment: I was hoping I could get away with it. The principle is once you have a group by, your select result can include, the group by fields, if a primary key, the contents of that row, and other fields needs to be wrapped in an aggreagation function.. Sorry. Fallback is the second query.

Comment: I tryed now adding every field and copy paste it to group by it "works" but i cant say for sure i get the right counts out of it (atm working with demo data)

i am realy thankfull for your help i will need to find another way to do it maybe a function or something that my route file isnt overflowing